# I want to fetch all those record which are greater then from a given date in database

Tags: mysql

Below is my query which is run but not give perfect answer

```
SELECT `event`.* 
FROM `events` AS `event` 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(event.event_start,'%m-%d-%Y') >=
      DATE_FORMAT('2011-03-15','%m-%d-%Y') ORDER BY `event_start` desc ";
```

I think '>' does not work with date format column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) command creates a string representing the date. Therefore, you are comparing strings representing the date, not the date itself.

```
SELECT `event`.* 
FROM `events` AS `event` 
WHERE event.event_start >= '2011-03-15'
ORDER BY `event_start` desc ";
```

If you absolutely have to use the DATE_FORMAT command (perhaps event_start is not a date column?) then ensure you are comparing with year, then month, then day, rather than month, day, year.

```
SELECT `event`.* 
FROM `events` AS `event` 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(event.event_start,'%y-%m-%d') >=
      DATE_FORMAT('2011-03-15','%y-%m-%d') ORDER BY `event_start` desc ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TIMESTAMPDIFF function:

```
SELECT `event`.* 
FROM `events` AS `event` 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2011-03-15', event.event_start) > 0
ORDER BY 'event_start' desc";
```

This should give you all events with event_start from 2011-03-16.
It is described here: [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Comment: I wouldn't use any "DIFF" functions in the where clause if you can help it as they will not be able to take advantage of any index on the table that includes the date columns.